# How to decode a json response in perl that contains pure perl boolean?

Tags: json, perl

I am getting a json response from an API endpoint that is something like this:

```
    {
            "items": [
                {
                    "key": "",
                    "groupReference": "mastercard-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "type": "firstPresentment-dms",
                    "created": "2023-01-27T10:07:56.038Z",
                    "entry": 1,
                    "isCorrection": false,
                    "reportingFor": "0000",
                    "network": "mastercard",
                    "fundsTransferDate": "2023-01-27",
                    "fundsTransferBookDate": "2023-01-27",
                    
                }
            ]
}
```

I have used decode_json() to decode this. The problem is since the isCorrection is a pure perl boolean value, the decoding doesn't work properly and I get this

```
Reference of JSON::PP::Boolean$VAR1 = bless( do{(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' );
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the decoding doesn't work properly

Oh, but it does. The [documentation for the mapping from JSON to Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP#JSON-%3E-PERL) includes this:

> **true, false**
>
> These JSON atoms become `JSON::PP::true` and `JSON::PP::false`, respectively. They are overloaded to act almost exactly like the numbers `1` and `0`. You can check whether a scalar is a JSON boolean by using the `JSON::PP::is_bool` function.

So if you treat the value you get as a boolean, everything will Just Work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON::PP;

my $response = '{
  "items": [
    {
      "key": "",
      "groupReference": "mastercard-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "type": "firstPresentment-dms",
      "created": "2023-01-27T10:07:56.038Z",
      "entry": 1,
      "isCorrection": false,
      "reportingFor": "0000",
      "network": "mastercard",
      "fundsTransferDate": "2023-01-27",
      "fundsTransferBookDate": "2023-01-27"
    }
  ]
}';


my $data = decode_json($response);

if ($data->{items}[0]{isCorrection}) {
  say "Value is true";
} else {
  say "Value is false";
}
```

Things will only go wrong if you break encapsulation and start expecting specific values there. But you can probably fix that using [OO version of the interface](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP#OBJECT-ORIENTED-INTERFACE) and the [`boolean_values()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP#boolean_values) or [`core_bools()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP#core_bools) methods.

Answer (score 3):

What you see is how it is supposed to work. This way, if you re-encode that as JSON, you get the right JSON boolean values and not 0 or 1.

Dave Cross's answer shows that you shouldn't have to think about it. But, if there's some reason you need to convert it to plain 1 or 0, there are some Perl idioms:

```
use v5.10;

use JSON;

foreach my $value ( qw(true false) ) {
    say "---- $value ----";
    my $hash = decode_json( qq({ "items": $value }) );
    say "conditional: " , $hash->{items} ? 1 : 0;
    say "plus: ",  0 + $hash->{items};
    say "double bang: ",  !! $hash->{items};
    say "plain: ",  $hash->{items};
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
---- true ----
conditional: 1
plus: 1
double bang: 1
plain: 1
---- false ----
conditional: 0
plus: 0
double bang:
plain: 0
```

Note that the `!!` in the false case does not give back zero. Instead, it's the empty string. I include that because you'll see that idiom to double negate a value, although that's more about turning a non-zero length string into 1 or the empty string.

The conditional version is probably more appropriate if you need to select one of two special values (perhaps for a database column):

```
my $insert_this_value = $hash->{items} ? $TRUE_VALUE : $FALSE_VALUE;
```

Comment: Re "*Instead, it's the empty string*', No. It's a scalar that contains both zero and the empty string, which makes it different than both zero and the empty string.

Comment: Yes, indeed. It shows up like that because of the `say` (or other stringy operation).